# loop through each input and loop again and compare

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see from the below snippet, I first get the current parent row (".role_td_holder") of the currently click button and find divs that has a class of ".role_wrapper" within it and then put it on a variable named "this_roletr" and then I loop through each .flatRoundedCheckbox input, created a global variable named "role_name" and then loop through each divs that has a class of "role_wrapper" and then get each text and put it on the global variable "role_name" and then within the loop of ".flatRoundedCheckbox input" I compare if the current looped input's name attribute content is equal to the role_name content, if it does then put checked property to this currently looped input else if it doesn't then set the checked property to false. As below snippets, it works but only one checkbox is checked when theres actually two .role_wrapper or multiple that matched its text to any of the .flatRoundedCheckbox input name (e.g. if theres two divs that has a class of "role_wrapper, only one checkbox is checked when supposedly, two checkbox must be checked that matched its name attribute content to those divs that has a class of "role_wrapper" text. Any help, ideas, suggestion, recommendation, help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", ".trigger", function(){
            var this_roletr = $(this).parents(".role_td_holder").find(".role_wrapper");
            $("#checkbox_container .flatRoundedCheckbox input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
               var checkbox = $(this); 
               this_roletr.each(function(){
                   var role_name = $(this).text();
                   if(checkbox.attr("name") === role_name){
                       checkbox.prop("checked", true);
                    }else{
                        checkbox.prop("checked", false);
                    }
                });


           });

    });
});
```

```css
table, theader, th, tbody, tr, td, a, .extend{max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;}
a:focus, a:active{outline: none;text-decoration: none;}
a, span, .cosbox_notify, .transation{-webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;-ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;-o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;}
.bgwhite{background: #fff;}
.center{margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
.clear{clear: both;float: none;}
.fade {transition: all 300ms linear 700ms;-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);-moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);-ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);-o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);transform: translate3d(0,0,0);opacity: 1;}
.fade.out {opacity: 0;}
.table_scroll, .overflow_container{overflow: auto;}
.table_scroll_y{overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;}
.table_scroll_x{overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;}
.align_left{float: left;}
.align_right{float: right;}
.display_table{display: table;}
.display_block{display: block;}
.overflow_hidden{overflow: hidden;}
.overflow_auto{overflow: auto};
.overflow_x{overflow-x: auto};
.overflow_y{overflow-y: auto};
.inline_block{display: inline-block;}
.divider{height: 10px;}
.padding_2px{padding: 2px;}
.padding_3px{padding: 3px;}
.padding_4px{padding: 4px;}
.padding_5px{padding: 5px;}
.padding_6px{padding: 6px;}
.padding_7px{padding: 7px;}
.padding_8px{padding: 8px;}
.padding_9px{padding: 9px;}
.padding_10px{padding: 10px;}
.margin_left2px{margin-left: 2px;}
.margin_left3px{margin-left: 3px;}
.margin_left4px{margin-left: 4px;}
.margin_left5px{margin-left: 5px;}
.margin_left6px{margin-left: 6px;}
.margin_left7px{margin-left: 7px;}
.margin_left8px{margin-left: 8px;}
.margin_left9px{margin-left: 9px;}
.margin_left10px{margin-left: 10px;}
.margin_right2px{margin-right: 2px;}
.margin_right3px{margin-right: 3px;}
.margin_right4px{margin-right: 4px;}
.margin_right5px{margin-right: 5px;}
.margin_right6px{margin-right: 6px;}
.margin_right7px{margin-right: 7px;}
.margin_right8px{margin-right: 8px;}
.margin_right9px{margin-right: 9px;}
.margin_right10px{margin-right: 10px;}
.margin_top2px{margin-top: 2px;}
.margin_top3px{margin-top: 3px;}
.margin_top4px{margin-top: 4px;}
.margin_top5px{margin-top: 5px;}
.margin_top6px{margin-top: 6px;}
.margin_top7px{margin-top: 7px;}
.margin_top8px{margin-top: 8px;}
.margin_top9px{margin-top: 9px;}
.margin_top10px{margin-top: 10px;}
.margin_bottom2px{margin-bottom: 2px;}
.margin_bottom3px{margin-bottom: 3px;}
.margin_bottom4px{margin-bottom: 4px;}
.margin_bottom5px{margin-bottom: 5px;}
.margin_bottom6px{margin-bottom: 6px;}
.margin_bottom7px{margin-bottom: 7px;}
.margin_bottom8px{margin-bottom: 8px;}
.margin_bottom9px{margin-bottom: 9px;}
.margin_bottom10px{margin-bottom: 10px;}
.status_approve{color: #76b729 !important;}
.status_reject{color: #eb5959 !important;}
.status_pending{color: #ebca59 !important;}
.green_button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: normal 13px 'mpregular', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 7px 3px 7px;
    width: 85px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #659d24;
    background: #76b729;
    text-align: center;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.green_button:hover{outline: none;color:#ffffff;background:#659d24 !important;border-bottom: 3px solid #659d24 !important;}
.green_button:focus, .green_button:active{outline: none;}
.flatRoundedCheckbox
{
    width: 40px;
    height: 21px;
    position: relative;
}
.flatRoundedCheckbox div
{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.flatRoundedCheckbox label
{
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;

    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 3px;
    background: #FFF;
    
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.flatRoundedCheckbox input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}
.flatRoundedCheckbox input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div
{
    background: #4fbe79;
}

.flatRoundedCheckbox input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
    left: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead><th>Full name</th><th>role</th><th>Option</th></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="role_td_holder">
      <td>Full name 1</td>
      <td>
        <div class="display_table center role_wrapper_container">
           <button class="draggable extend role_wrapper">Role 1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="display_table center role_wrapper_container">
           <button class="draggable extend role_wrapper">Role 2</button>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
         <button class="trigger">Click</button>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="role_td_holder">
      <td>Full name 1</td>
      <td>
        <div class="display_table center role_wrapper_container">
           <button class="draggable extend role_wrapper">Role 1</button>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
         <button class="trigger">Click</button>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="role_td_holder">
      <td>Full name 1</td>
      <td>
        <div class="display_table center role_wrapper_container">
           <button class="draggable extend role_wrapper">Role 1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="display_table center role_wrapper_container">
           <button class="draggable extend role_wrapper">Role 2</button>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
         <button class="trigger">Click</button>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="extend clear padding_7px overflow_auto" id="checkbox_container">
             
               <div class="display_table align_left margin_right3px margin_bottom3px">
            <div class="display_block align_left margin_right3px checkbox_label" style="font-size: 13px;">Role 1</div>
            <div class="flatRoundedCheckbox align_left">
                <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="Role 1">
                <label></label>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
               <div class="display_table align_left margin_right3px margin_bottom3px">
            <div class="display_block align_left margin_right3px checkbox_label" style="font-size: 13px;">Role 2</div>
            <div class="flatRoundedCheckbox align_left">
                <input type="checkbox" value="6" name="Role 2">
                <label></label>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
               <div class="display_table align_left margin_right3px margin_bottom3px">
            <div class="display_block align_left margin_right3px checkbox_label" style="font-size: 13px;">Role 3</div>
            <div class="flatRoundedCheckbox align_left">
                <input type="checkbox" value="7" name="Role 3">
                <label></label>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$(this).parents(".role_td_holder").find(".role_wrapper").each(function(){
                var role_name = $.trim($(this).text());
                $("#checkbox_container .flatRoundedCheckbox  input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){ 
                    if($(this).attr("name") === role_name){
                        $(this).prop("checked", true);
                    }
                   // alert("asdasd");
                });

            });
```